# Filtering backbone collection on multiple attribtues

Tags: backbone.js

Is this a good approach to filtering a backbone collection on multiple attributes:

```
filterData: function(params) {
    // store original data for clearing filters
    this.originalModels = this.models.slice();
    for (var key in params) {
        var val = params[key];
        // if we are dealing with multiple values in an array
        // i.e. ['ford','bmw','mazda']
        if (typeof val === "object") {
            var union = [];
            for (var k in val) {
                var subval = val[k];
                var matched = _.filter(this.models, function(house) {
                   return house.get(key) == subval; 
                });
                union = union.concat(matched);
            }
            this.models = union;
        } else {
           var results = _.filter(this.models, function(house) {
               return house.get(key) == val;
           });
           this.models = results;
        }
    } // end for
    return this.reset(this.models);
},
clearFilters: function() {
    return this.reset(this.originalModels);
}
```

I tested it and it allows me to filter a collection in the following manner:

```
filterParams = {brand:['ford','bmw','mazda'], color:black}

carCollection.filterData(filterParams);
```

It seems to work, but I don't know if there is a better way of doing this.

I tested the `Backbone.Collection.where()` method, but it does not work if I want to say `brand: ['bmw','mazda','ford']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
filterData: function(params) {
    // store original data for clearing filters
    this.originalModels = this.models.slice();

    _.each(params, function(val, key){
        if (typeof val !== 'object') val = [ val ];
        this.models = _.filter(this.models, function(model){
            return _.indexOf(val, model.get(key)) !== -1;
        }, this);
    }, this);
    return this.reset(this.models);
}
```

Comment: thanks, how would add support for ranges? for example: price between 20000-50000

Comment: inside the for each loop, `this` is undefined. I fixed it by adding a `var that = this` above the `_.each`

Comment: @alexBrand Ranges are more complicated, so you'd probably want to support that by a separate case. Your solution for `this` works, but I've updated my answer witha  better way. Pass `this` as the third param to `each` and `filter`.

Comment: what is the difference between passing `this` and referencing it with `that`?

Comment: @alexBrand Functionality-wise they are the same, it's just one line shorter and easier to read by now adding another useless variable.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js collections have access to a number of underscore.js methods, including filter().

```
carCollection.reset(carCollection.filter(function(car){
  return $.inArray(car.brand,['ford','bmw','mazda']) && car.color === 'black';
}));
```

Not tested, but that should work if you use jQuery. If not, you can create your own inArray() function

Comment: I need to be able to pass a filterParams object to the collection, such as `filterParams = {brand:['ford','bmw'],color:'black',price:20000}`

Comment: Ah. In that case, my answer would wind up being pretty close to what you have in practice.